# CSS @font-face not rendering icons in production (instead it shows only unicodes) works fine in local

Tags: css, angular, unicode, font-face, glyphicons

I am trying to render icons from the Icomon library in my Angular application.
I'm suspecting it to be a problem of how my CSS files are included

withing the index.html page of icomon fonts we have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></head>
```

within the style.css I have the following declarations:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'gtap-icons';
  src:  url('fonts/gtap-icons.eot?5cufps');
  src:  url('fonts/gtap-icons.eot?5cufps#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/gtap-icons.ttf?5cufps') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/gtap-icons.woff?5cufps') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/gtap-icons.svg?5cufps#gtap-icons') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}
```

Icons contents are loaded as (for example)

```
.icon-ac_unit:before {
  content: "\e900";
}
.icon-access_alarms:before {
  content: "\e901";
}
```

My folder structure

[image]

Inside fonts folder I have eot, ttf, woff and SVG files.

In my local I can see the icons like:

[image]

But in production it looks like:

[image]

Note:
I am using utf-8 charset and there are no errors/warning in console related to fonts

I can see that the font is downloaded properly
[image]

I am not sure exactly what is going wrong. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that is a font issue at all. If it was, then you should get different _characters_ shown (or the symbol for a missing glyph) - but it makes no sense that this would "fall back" to showing the actual hexadecimal byte codes, if there was any problem related to the font.

Comment: Your screenshot indicates, the content was at some point unnecessarily **escaped** to something like `\\e901`. Maybe a wrong configuration in a bundling or scss compiling process?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the font files are not actually being loaded.  Check your server's MIME type settings to make sure it knows how to deliver each of those font file types.

If you open your browser devtools can you see if the font files are actually being downloaded correctly?

For example:

[image]

Comment: I could see that the font is loaded properly

Comment: The same in the Network tab too?  You see it being downloaded properly with no issues?  Perhaps something with the font name or CSS identifier is being changed somehow?

Comment: In the network tab also able to see the font downloaded properly

Comment: well...  ¯\\_ (ツ)_/¯

Comment: Maybe somewhere the text content is overridden, I am trying to figure out.